# Openpyxl gives an inconsistent error message

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have the following function that will read from an excel workbook with the openpyxl library:

```
import openpyxl

def read_excel(path):
    excel_workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path, read_only = True)
    # other logic
    return None
```

I can call that function like this:

```
read_excel("C:/Users/anon/Desktop/Current Projects/Test Files/Test.xlsm ")
```

And it returns this error:

```
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support .xlsm  file
format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: .xlsx,.xlsm,
.xltx,.xltm
```

That error message confuses me.  It's telling me that it doesn't support the `.xlsm` file format, and that it supports the `.xlsm` file format.  The file opens just fine in excel, why won't openpyxl read my Excel file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an extra whitespace character in the error message after `.xlsm`.  Remove the whitespace character at the end of the path string you call the function with, and the function runs without error.

```
read_excel("C:/Users/anon/Desktop/Current Projects/Test Files/Test.xlsm")
```

Comment: I spent some time examining my Excel file before I spotted this simple error.  My goal here is to provide a reference for anyone else who gets this confusing error message for a similar reason.

Answer (score 1):

the same problem bothered me a lot also today, and finally I updated openpyxl from 2.3.2 to 2.3.5, and this problem disappeared.

Although I am using Anaconda, sometimes using pip to update the packages might be a good try.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Unfortunately Jinstrong can not leave comments on other people's posts until he has 50 reputation.  This is useful information, I'm OK with his workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using PyQt5 and had the same problem. I found that adding `_filter` fixed the problem.  The full line reads:

```
fileName, _filter = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Lists", "", "xlsx files *.xlsx")
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, did you post this on the right question?  It looks like you are solving a different problem :-)

Comment: I received the exact same error as MackM and solved it as stated in my reply.  I didn't mean to confuse the subject.

Answer (score -1):

First, change the cwd(). When passing the file name, you can just copy the name of the file and paste it instead of typing it manually. The error may arise from some undetected nuances.